# Draw a circle in AutoCAD from C

Tags: c, autocad

I am trying to draw a cirle in an already running instance of AutoCAD, append it to the existing drawing.

Is that possible? What is the easiest way?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned "an already running instance of AutoCAD", I'm assuming you want to automate AutoCAD, usually via ActiveX COM Automation. You should use AcadApplication interface (and **cannot** use AcDb or .NET Mgd references).

Here is a ActiveX C++ generic code sample from [this blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/12/adding-an-attribute-to-a-block-definition-using-c-comactivex-automation-in-objectarx.html). Note the acac19enu.tlb reference, where 19 stands for the AutoCAD version. The current one is AutoCAD 2017 (library version: 21).

```
#import "acax19ENU.tlb" no_namespace
#include <rxmfcapi.h>
#include <axpnt3d.h>
void fAddAttribute()
{
  try
  {
    // get the ActiveX application object from AutoCAD, inc ref count
    IAcadApplicationPtr pAcadApp = acedGetAcadWinApp()->GetIDispatch(TRUE);
    // now get the active doc
    IAcadDocumentPtr pActiveDoc = pAcadApp->ActiveDocument;
    IAcadBlockPtr pBlock = NULL;
    TCHAR *pBlkName = _T("some_block_name");
    // create an activex compatible insertion point3d
    AcAxPoint3d axInsPnt(0,0,0);
    // now add the block name
    pBlock = pActiveDoc->Blocks->Add(axInsPnt.asVariantPtr(),_bstr_t(pBlkName));
    // now add an Attribute to the block
    IAcadAttributePtr pAttDef;
    pAttDef = pBlock->AddAttribute(1.0, (AcAttributeMode)0 ,
      _bstr_t("Type the employee name"), axInsPnt.asVariantPtr(),
      _bstr_t("empname"),_bstr_t(""));
    //attribute added
  }
  catch(_com_error &es)
  {
    acutPrintf(L"\nError : %s", es.ErrorMessage());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find anything in C but here's a C# example from the [Developer Guide](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-3cf7.htm,topicNumber=d0e30666):

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;

[CommandMethod("AddCircle")]
public static void AddCircle()
{
  // Get the current document and database
  Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;

  // Start a transaction
  using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
      // Open the Block table for read
      BlockTable acBlkTbl;
      acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId,
                                   OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

      // Open the Block table record Model space for write
      BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec;
      acBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                      OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

      // Create a circle that is at 2,3 with a radius of 4.25
      Circle acCirc = new Circle();
      acCirc.SetDatabaseDefaults();
      acCirc.Center = new Point3d(2, 3, 0);
      acCirc.Radius = 4.25;

      // Add the new object to the block table record and the transaction
      acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acCirc);
      acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acCirc, true);

      // Save the new object to the database
      acTrans.Commit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure C it may be complicated, so good luck. 
But if you use C++ and ARX try this:

```
Acad::ErrorStatus AddCircle(AcGePoint3d center , double r , AcDbObjectId& id , AcDbBlockTableRecord* pBlock)
{
    AcDbCircle* pCirEnt = NULL;
    pCirEnt  = new AcDbCircle();
    pCirEnt->setCenter(center);
    pCirEnt->setRadius(r);
    Acad::ErrorStatus es = Add(pCirEnt , pBlock);
    es = pCirEnt->close();
    id = pCirEnt->objectId();
    return es ;
}


Acad::ErrorStatus Add( AcDbEntity * pEnt, AcDbBlockTableRecord* Blok)
{
    if ( !pEnt )    {       
        return Acad::eNullEntityPointer  ;
    }

    Acad::ErrorStatus es;
    if (!Blok)
    {
        Blok = getModelSpace(AcDb::kForWrite);
        if (!Blok) return Acad::eInvalidOwnerObject;
    }
    if (Blok->isWriteEnabled() == Adesk::kFalse )
    {
        AcDbObject* pObj = NULL;    
        es = acdbOpenObject(pObj,Blok->objectId (),AcDb::kForWrite) ;
        Blok = AcDbBlockTableRecord::cast(pObj);
    }
    if ((es = Blok->appendAcDbEntity(pEnt)) != Acad::eOk )  // eAlreadyInDb = wcześniej wstawione do innego bloku.
    {
        Blok->close();
        return es;
    }
    Blok->close();
    return Acad::eOk;
}

AcDbBlockTableRecord* getModelSpace(AcDb::OpenMode mode)
{
    AcDbBlockTableRecord* Blok = NULL;
    Acad::ErrorStatus es;
    AcDbDatabase * pDb = acdbHostApplicationServices()->workingDatabase();
    if (!pDb) return NULL;
    AcDbBlockTable* pTbl = NULL;
    if ((es= pDb->getBlockTable(pTbl, AcDb::kForRead) ) != Acad::eOk  )
        return NULL;
    if ((es = pTbl->getAt(ACDB_MODEL_SPACE, Blok, mode)) !=  Acad::eOk )
    {
        pTbl->close();
        return NULL;
    }
    pTbl->close();

    return Blok;
}
```